# HTML Submit Button Handling in Java EE

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee

I have a question regarding Java EE's handling of an event created by an HTML form submit button: `<input type = "submit"/>`. And, I really have no idea where to begin in taking apart this process, conceptually (I am missing a major foundational "piece of the puzzle").

Let's say I am trying to grab two pieces of information from a user via a website: a first name and a last name. These values are entered by the user into two separate HTML Text Fields, e.g. `<input type = "text"/>`.

In order to make this question as simple as possible, let's pretend I am not trying to validate the entered data.

After the user has entered his or her data, he or she clicks an HTML Submit Button. My question is twofold: first [1], how do I listen for an HTML event in Java EE; second [2], in response to the event, how do I retrieve that entered data? Do I need to `id` the the tags?

*I am not trying to post the data to a database in this scenario.* Also, **I am trying to keep the question simple, so I have left out the surrounding `<form>` tags, etc., here.** Really, this question is about the Java EE side - not an HTML "how-to"; however, below, I have gone in and posted the HTML to demonstrate to readers what should be done.

I have researched the heck out of this (*Beginning Java EE 7* and the Oracle Documentation) and can't figure it out, primarily because found resources handle each topic individually.

#### HTML Code

```
<form name="input" action=<!-- action needed --> method="get">
    <input type="text" id="firstName"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML you should have a `<FORM>` element around your inputs and submit button with an `action` attribute, the URL that is in that attribute needs to map to a class that extends [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html), it will commonly have one of two methods, `doGet()` for HTTP Get Requests and `doPost()` for HTTP Post requests.  From the documentation:

> Provides an abstract class to be subclassed to create an HTTP servlet suitable for a Web site. A subclass of HttpServlet must override at least one method, usually one of these:

```
doGet, if the servlet supports HTTP GET requests
doPost, for HTTP POST requests
doPut, for HTTP PUT requests
doDelete, for HTTP DELETE requests
init and destroy, to manage resources that are held for the life of the servlet
getServletInfo, which the servlet uses to provide information about itself
```

These methods accept two arguments the first one being a variable of type [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), this variable has a method called [`getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) that will let you pull out values from the request by their `input name`.

Comment: What sources (text sources) would you recommend someone pick up to help them learn Java EE?

Comment: It's a really large platform that I don't think I fully comprehend.  I've done all of my work building an ever expanding set of apps built on Tomcat (which seems like just about as much Java EE as I can handle).  Honestly I started with simple apps and added complexity incrementally.

Answer (score 2):

Servlets are HTTP listeners in JavaEE. Have a look at this portion of the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets005.htm) regarding servlets:

> The general pattern for a service method is to **extract information** from the request, access external resources, and then populate the response, based on that information.

The HTTP POST that occurs when you hit the submit button should be sent to a servlet, which unpacks the request parameters and does something with them.  The response is written back to the view of your choosing.

In this particular case, you might write to a start page for authenticated and authorized users if the username and password are acceptable or a "sorry" page if not.

I think tags should have ids.

You cannot leave out the HTTP "how to".  You have to use `<form>` tags.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Bless you, user! That makes complete sense. All the material I have does not deal with the interaction between HTML and Java EE (which is ludicrous, in some sense).

Comment: @Thomas note that the HTTP POST won't occur unless you wrap the `<input type="submit" />` or `<button>` with a `<form>` tag or you specify a JavaScript method in the `onclick` attribute of the HTML component that fires the HTTP request.